# Change currency format to generic number using sed

Tags: sed, awk, regular-expression

I am working on a large csv file with all coma separated entries. The entire document is composed of plain numbers, except for a few columns reflecting currencies that are formatted as text. For example, one such entry may look like `"$12,345.67"` and another one like `"$1,234,567.89"`  (double quote symbols are also included as part of the entries). Here is an example of a full record (one single line) of data:

```
123,7,11,"$343,700.14","$34,928.63","$377,000.00","$15,421.92",19,2
```

I would like to do some processing on this data file and therefore, I want to reformat such text fields to become plain numbers (i.e., getting rid of double quotes and comas). I think a regex pattern replacement with `sed` should do the job for me, but I am not sure what that regular expression looks like at all. Any idea would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example of an entire record?

Comment: Just added one.

Answer (score 1):

Update: adapting the answer from [Replace spaces only in between quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5499798/168034) to handle this problem.

Command:

```
echo '123,7,11,"$343,700.14","$34,928.63","$377,000.00","$15,421.92",19,2' |
awk -F\" '{OFS="\""; for (i = 2; i < NF; i += 2) gsub(/[$,]/,"",$i); gsub(/"/,""); print}'
```

Output:

```
123,7,11,343700.14,34928.63,377000.00,15421.92,19,2
```

The first `gsub` removes `$`s and `,`s inside double quotes. The second remove the quotes themselves.

Leaving original answer below in case it helps.

If I understand you correctly a simple search and replace would do it

```
echo '"$1,234,567.89"' | sed 's/[$,"]//g'
```

Output `1234567.89`.

What this does is that it substitute (`s`) characters matching (`[]`) `$`, `,` and `"` with nothing (empty between the last two `/`. The `g` flag makes it apply globally, replacing all instances (otherwise only the first instance in a line would be replaced).

How to apply this to the whole file depends on the format of the file. If there is nothing else in the file that has double quotes, dollar signs and comma, this should be good:

```
sed 's/[$,"]//g' /path/to/file
```

Comment: Thanks @phunehehe. This looks pretty close, except for the fact that it would also eliminate all other comas separating entries in the file. Am I right?

Comment: Right. My little research suggests that you need `awk`, but my `awk` is not good :) Here is a hint in the right direction http://stackoverflow.com/q/5499798/168034

Comment: -1 the script does not solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

it is simple to express what should be done:

1 For each string that is enclosed between `"$` and `"` delete all `,`
   2 delete the surrounding `"$` and `"`

This are sed expressions. If you use it on the command linen you have to quote it appropriately. 
It is simpler to put it in a file, e.g. command.sed, and call it by

```
sed -f command.sed data.csv
```

This is the program that implements the these two steps:

```
:repeat
s/"\$\([^,"]*\),/"$\1/g 
t repeat
s/"\$\([^"]*\)"/\1/g
```

This [document](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) helped me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

How this currency value is displayed depends on your CSV viewer, why wouldn't you change the "view" e.g in Excel rather than changing this field?

YAnyway, you might have multiple fields in your csv field, so it would be safer to use a handler script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1 } );
while ( my $row = $csv->getline(\*STDIN) ) {
    foreach my $item (@$row)
    {
        $item =~ s/,//g if ($item =~ /^\$[0-9,.]+$/);
    }
    $csv->print (\*STDOUT, $row);
    print "\n";
}
```

Usage:  ./csv.pl < in.csv > ou.csv

Input:

```
abc,"$1,243,311.99",def
abc2,"$43,311.99",def2
```

Output:

```
abc,$1243311.99,def
abc2,$43311.99,def2
```

Comment: Thanks @warl0ck. I am getting the following error: `Can't locate Text/CSV.pm in @INC`. Sounds like I have some perl library missing, but unfortunately do not have privilege to install any module on the machine I am currently running. Do you know of any way to bypass this error?

Comment: @Ali use cpan then, `cpan install Text::CSV`

Comment: sounds like I do not have permission to install additional libraries on this computer. I'll try to have it installed on my own machine later today and see if I can work it out. Thanks :)

Comment: @Ali cpan will install the module intto your user account's home folder

Answer (score 0):

A slightly convoluted awk solution, based on [CSV parsing with awk](http://backreference.org/2010/04/17/csv-parsing-with-awk/)

```
{
$0=$0",";                                  # yes, cheating
while($0) {
  gsub(/\$/,"",$0)
  match($0,/ *"[^"]*" *,|[^,]*,/);
  sf=f=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);          # save what matched in sf
  gsub(/^ *"?|"? *,$/,"",f);               # remove extra stuff
  gsub(/,/,"",f);
  if($0 ~ /,[^,]+,$/){
    printf "%s,",f;
  }else{
    printf "%s",f;
  }
  sub(sf,"");                              # "consume" what matched
}
printf "\n"
}
```

Saved the above as csv.awk and ran like so:

```
echo '123,7,11,"$343,700.14","$34,928.63","$377,000.00","$15,421.92",19,2'|awk -f csv.awk
123,7,11,343700.14,34928.63,377000.00,15421.92,19,2
```

Comment: Thanks @tink. I tried to run your script on the file, but it is getting too long to terminate. The command I ran was `cat data.csv | awk -f csv.awk > updated.csv`. I think something in the script (or the command I ran) is not optimized for this purpose. Using openoffice's calc, I was able to the same task in a few minutes on the same file. My impression is that `awk` can do much faster on this job than calc, hum?!

Comment: Hard to say what might be going on there.  Is all of the data actually formed like the single line you pasted above?  If there are deviations in delimiters, or embedded special characters that might be interpreted as part of a RegEx awk might get thrown off.